# JavaScript. Click to one to change color, click other to restore, many elements, how to?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to give an .svg world map a JavaScript "click change color" function.

**EXPECTED BEHAVIOR:**

Click one country to change its color, click other country to change color but previous clicked restore to its default color.

**BUGS I HAVE NOW:**

Click one country, it's color changed, but click other, the previous color remained.

**CODE WITH BUGS(UNEXPECTED):**

The svg structure:

```
<g name="us"><path>...</path></g>
<g name="au"><path>...</path></g>
<g name="es"><path>...</path></g>
.....
<g name="ca"><path>...</path></g>
```

The JavaScript part:

```
(function () {
  var world = document.getElementById("world");  // The svg file
  world.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var doc = world.getSVGDocument();
    doc.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
      var target = e.target,
          target.style.fill = "#eee";
    });
  });
}());
```

Pure JavaScript needed, no jQuery.

If the elements(countries) is three or five, I can do that, but the elements are too many, is there a compact way to get this effect?

Thank you for your attention, help me please if you can. : )

Comment: How about updat fill style of all svg, then update fill style of clicked svg?

Comment: Thank you, I've tried but it didn't work LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could deselect all elements on click and afterwards select the one that was clicked:

```js
const svg = document.getElementById('world');
const elements = svg.getElementsByTagName('g');

svg.onclick = ({ target }) => {
  // make sure we clicked on a group or a child of one
  // and do nothing if we havent
  const g = target.closest('g'); 
  if (!g) return;
  
  // remove selected class from all
  // and add it to the one clicked
  [...elements].forEach(e => e.classList.remove('selected'));
  g.classList.add('selected');
};
```

```css
.selected {
  fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<svg id="world" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 30 30">
<g data-country="1"><rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"/></g>
<g data-country="2"><rect x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10"/></g>
<g data-country="3"><rect x="20" y="20" width="10" height="10"/></g>
<g data-country="4"><rect x="0" y="20" width="10" height="10"/></g>
</svg>
```